# ¿Son intercambiables "imagínate" y "date cuenta"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-entre-palabras

¿Son intercambiables "imagínate" y "date cuenta" en este ejemplo?

> **Imagínate**,  Próspero está hablando en muchos idiomas.
>
> **Date cuenta**,  Próspero está hablando en muchos idiomas.

Answer (score 3):

En el contexto de las oraciones:

> Imagínate: Próspero está hablando en muchos idiomas.
>
> Date cuenta: Próspero está hablando en muchos idiomas.

(la coma no me parece un buen signo de puntuación: la cambié por dos puntos)

"imagínate" y "date cuenta" son similares por cuanto se invita al interlocutor a tomar conciencia de una situación.

En el DLE, las definiciones que nos interesan dicen:

- imaginar:  Representar en la mente la imagen de algo o de alguien

(En este contexto donde es una realidad que Próspero está hablando en muchos idiomas, no aplica la definición que dice: Concebir algo con la fantasía.)

- darse cuenta de algo:

  1. loc. verb. Advertirlo, percatarse de ello.
  2. loc. verb. coloq. Comprenderlo, entenderlo.

La diferencia semántica entre ambos verbos surge claramente de sus definiciones: *imaginar(se)* tiene que ver con la representación mental de una imagen, mientras que *darse cuenta* se relaciona con una idea (más abstracta que la imagen).

Las dos expresiones no suelen ser intercambiables, pues "imagínate" (que puede seguir con indicativo o subjuntivo) puede apuntar a una realidad o a una fantasía mientras que "date cuenta" (seguido siempre por indicativo) sólo dirige la atención hacia una realidad:

- **Imagínate** que Próspero **habla** muchos idiomas (realidad o fantasía)
- **Imagínate** que Próspero **hable** muchos idiomas (fantasía)
- **Date cuenta** de que Próspero **habla** muchos idiomas (realidad)

Comment: ¿¿ „Date cuenta“ significa „piénsalo“ ??

Comment: @Hausmeister33 Parecido a "piénsalo" pero más cercano a "reconócelo", "admítelo".

Comment: What about fijate, or should I ask a new question?

Comment: Yes, "fíjate" is similar to "date cuenta" when it involves a mental (non-visual) process. "fíjate" is more of a perceptive verb in a sentence like: *Fíjate cómo Próspero habla muchos idiomas.*

Comment: @dewey - To me, "date cuenta" is like "realize," and "fíjate" is like "notice/observe."  In "date cuenta" there's a light bulb going on -- a realization.  In "fíjate," it could be simply a way to ask the other person to pay attention (to you, as you're talking, or looking for a landmark en route to some place, etc.). // Sure, it could be an interesting question if it hasn't been asked yet.  Good idea.

Comment: Con respecto al último ejemplo, tengo entendido que debe ser "Date cuenta de que..."

Comment: @MauricioMartinez Es verdad. Es tan habitual usarlo sin "de" en la lengua coloquial que incurrí en un error. Lo corrijo. Dice el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas: «dar(se) cuenta. Esta locución verbal va siempre seguida de un complemento precedido de la preposición *de*. […] Debe evitarse, **en el habla esmerada**, la supresión de la preposición *de* cuando el complemento es una oración subordinada introducida por la conjunción *que*».